# How to move TFS commands in Visual Studio from right-click menu into sub menu?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Since we have installed TFS as our source code control system, my right-click menu in Visual Studio 2010 is ridiculously long!  I know how to customize the context menus, but having to do it in all those places is painstaking...   is there any addin that will automatically move all the TFS-related items into a sub-menu.

I miss how Ankh did this for SVN...    :-(

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can do what you want by exporting your settings, editing the exported xml, and then importing it back in.  I've been wanting to try something like this, but only just now discovered that this info is exported/imported.  Will give it a try here shortly.